# I can't apply auto increment for mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

> "INSERT INTO Fn_Registration VALUES ( '"+ txtFirstName.Text + "', '" + txtLastName.Text + "', " + " '" + txtEmailId.Text + "', " + " '" + txtPassword.Text + "', " + " '" + txtPanNumber.Text + "', " + " '" + txtAddress1.Text + "', " + " '" + txtAddress2.Text + "', " + " '" + txtFaxNo.Text + "'," + " '" + txtFirmName.Text + "', " + " '" + txtPhoneNumber.Text + "', " + " '" + txtTinNumber.Text + "','" + txtAccountsStart.Text + "','" + txtAccountsEnd.Text + "','" + cbbVat.Text + "', " + " '" + cbbstates.Text + "', " + " '" + txtCity.Text + "', '" + txtBankName.Text + "', '" + txtAccountNumber.Text + "', " + " '" + txtIFSCCode.Text + "', " + " '" + txtBN1.Text + "', " + " '" + txtAC1.Text + "', " + " '" + txtIFSC1.Text + "', " + " '" + txtBN2.Text + "', " + " '" + txtAC2.Text + "', " + " '" + txtIFSC2.Text + "')";

this is my insert code into mysql database where id num must be auto increamented,,, but mysql doesnot performs auto incrementation can any one help .........

**C# code**

```
string regInset = "INSERT INTO Fn_Registration VALUES ('" + 101 + "', '"+ 
txtFirstName.Text + "', '" + txtLastName.Text + "', " + " '" + txtEmailId.Text +
 "', " + " '" + txtPassword.Text + "', " + " '" + txtPanNumber.Text + "', " + " '" + 
txtAddress1.Text + "', " + " '" + txtAddress2.Text + "', " + " '" + txtFaxNo.Text +
 "'," + " '" + txtFirmName.Text + "', " + " '" + txtPhoneNumber.Text + "', " + " '" 
+ txtTinNumber.Text + "','" + txtAccountsStart.Text + "','" + txtAccountsEnd.Text + 
"','" + cbbVat.Text + "', " + " '" + cbbstates.Text + "', " + " '" + txtCity.Text +
 "', '" + txtBankName.Text + "', '" + txtAccountNumber.Text + "', " + " '" + 
txtIFSCCode.Text + "', " + " '" + txtBN1.Text + "', " + " '" + txtAC1.Text + "', " + 

" '" + txtIFSC1.Text + "', " + " '" + txtBN2.Text + "', " + " '" + txtAC2.Text + "', " 
+ " '" + txtIFSC2.Text + "')";

cmd = new MySqlCommand(regInset, con);
da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Fn_Registration");
this.clearData();
```

Comment: please don't write queries and pass parameters directly, this is one of the bad standards . To answer your question you should mention the id as identity column in the database, nothing you need to configure here.

Comment: what column should be autoincremented? the one where you put 101? or some other? do you have it set to autoincrement?

Comment: the which i have put 101 and i have set the column to autoincreament...when i tried to enter second time 101 doesnt perform auto increament and is shows primary key violation as i have given primary key for that column.... @Uriel_SVK

Comment: Check answer of Bob Brinks, if you input 101 it wont autoincrement, you have to exclude the column that you want autoincremented

Comment: btw, what do you think would happen if i put `'); drop table Fn_Registration;` in one of those textboxes?(dont do it!) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1):

In your insert query you can use:

```
INSERT INTO Fn_Registration(Names,of,columns,that,you,want,to,give,a,value) VALUES(values,for,those,columns);
```

If you then exclude the id column from the names of columns you want to give a value, SQL should automatically increment the value.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can be made to auto increment on a table by modifying that table as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY id_Column INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

[MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)